How to Diagnose/Trouble-shoot Slow Task Manager Open
Computer: Dell XPS 8930
O/S: Windows 10 Home 64-bit, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700, 64.0 GB RAM
Version: 22H2, build 19045.4894
I am having a hard time describing the problem my machine is having...it’s difficult to be comprehensive/detailed, but various activities (program start-up or close; starting Task Manager; right-clicking an open program tab in the taskbar to display pop-up menu; certain other clicks/events) sometimes take inordinate amounts of time, like seconds to half a minute, to complete or open.  The lag opening Task Manager is especially notable, IMO, as I always understood that to be a high priority request, as well as very low-level (re: operating system) command.  I just tried that now and it took about 8-10 seconds.
Results from running SFCcommand ( with /scannow option) and DISM command (trying both /CheckHealth and /ScanHealth options) indicate no issues, other than SFC re-adds some Windows bloat items (.lnk files) I never use to the Start Menu\Programs\ folder, e.g. “Accessibility”, “Accessories”, “Administrative Tools”, etc. as reported in the CBS.log file.  But re-adding those have no impact on my issue.
I use Windows Firewall, Microsoft Defender, and an intelligent/serious VPN, and perform scans for malware, etc. regularly, so it very unlikely my issue is due to some sort of virus or something similar.  So I am at a loss as to how to even zero in on the issue much less trouble-shoot.  Any thoughts?
These Superuser threads seemed maybe relevant, but did not actually help:
File Explorer becomes unresponsive for a minute on startup (along with Taskbar) and always on refreshing (F5)
Significant OS X lag when listing directories/files

edit: one time bump to top of queue

I bumped this (one time) to top of queue.  Sorta surprised there we no takers :--/
